# Odoo Overwrite delete record confirmation dialog

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

Hello I need to add some information to the delete record confirmation dialog on Odoo 12, adding some information of how many dependent records will be deleted. Something like:

```
Are you sure you want to delete this record ?
Doing this you will lose N records.
```

Currently is defined on "addons/web/static/src/js/views/basic/basic_controller.js" on `_deleteRecords` method. But if I change it there it will be changed for all my modules.

I'm wondering if there is a method to overwrite this... Or my other idea is to hide the button and use a wizard to do it.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default odoo can do that from xml file but if you need dynamic message than
please create one transient model for wizard and this model have two fields which is your message field and your main form view id after that you simply override the method `unlink` and in method do your computations if you want confirmation in deletion then return from that condition like this:

```
     return{
        'type':'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name':'Message',
        'res_model':'your.wizard.model',
        'view_type':'form',
        'view_mode':'form',
        'target':'new',
        'context':{'thesis_obj':self.id,'text_message_field':'course Work completed'},
        'res_id':value.id                
      }
```

After wizard opened you have your wizard's form view right?
in wizard form view if user click on **OK** button then call your original method from which you have to do it in first place.

**Wizard View Reference:**

```
<record id="wizard_message_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Approval Message</field>
  <field name="model">your.wizard.model</field>
  <field name="type">form</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <form string="Message">
          <separator string="Message" colspan="6"/>
          <field name="text_message" colspan="4" nolabel="1" readonly="1"  widget="html"/>                                                            
          <newline/>
          <separator colspan="6"/>
          <footer>
              <button name="btn_approve_oric" type="object" string="OK" class="oe_highlight"/>                             
              <button special="cancel" string="No"/>                    
          </footer>                                    
      </form>
  </field>
```

Feel free to ask.